# composer install in Dockerfile not saving dependencies

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose

I have some trouble to dockerize a Symfony project. At the first start from cloning from git repo the dependencies have to installed through composer.

I have read many questions with the same background but i cant get it working.

i show u first my Dockerfile:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.1
ARG APP_ENV=dev

# Prod image
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS app_php

# Update
RUN apk --no-cache update
RUN apk --no-cache add bash git

# Install Node
RUN apk --no-cache add --update nodejs npm
RUN apk --no-cache add --update python3
RUN apk --no-cache add --update make
RUN apk --no-cache add --update g++

# Install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Symfony CLI
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

# WORK DIR
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# prevent the reinstallation of vendors at every changes in the source code
COPY composer.* symfony.* ./
RUN set -eux; \
if [ -f composer.json ]; then \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress; \
    composer clear-cache; \
fi

RUN set -eux; \
mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
if [ -f composer.json ]; then \
    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev; \
    composer dump-env prod; \
    composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync; \
fi



# copy sources
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN rm -Rf docker/

# Start Symfony server on Port 8000
EXPOSE 8000
#RUN symfony console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

i can see that the packages were installed through the build process, but after `docker-compose up` the vendor folder isnt set.

Do u have an idea to solve this?

Comment: did you find `composer.json` file in your `WORKDIR`, both commands of composer, run only when this file is present.

Comment: yes, this file is present and the command works as expected. the only problem is that the vendors files are not saved in the container

Answer (score 0):

Running it for you, indeed there is no vendors files where you woudl expect them.

if you run a shell on your container you would see what's really happening:

Get your created container id or tag with `docker image ls`
And run it:

```
docker run --rm -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash
```

```bash
bash-5.1# ls /var/www/html/
Dockerfile  composer.1  composer.2  symfony.1   var
bash-5.1# ls -al /root/.composer/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            50 Aug 14 15:47 .
drwx------    1 root     root            16 Aug 14 15:48 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           799 Aug 14 15:47 keys.dev.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           799 Aug 14 15:47 keys.tags.pub
bash-5.1# ls /usr/bin/composer
/usr/bin/composer
bash-5.1# ls /usr/local/bin/composer 
/usr/local/bin/composer
bash-5.1# which composer
/usr/local/bin/composer
bash-5.1# which symfony
/usr/local/bin/symfony
bash-5.1#
```

The which command would make you realize:

- you don't need to copy composer when you already install it
- /usr/local/bin is already part of the PATH
- The current ENV command is not necessary plus pointing to a non existing folder.

FYI to keep it slim I have created fake symfony.* and composer.* files and have no composer.json (not shared here).

I hope this helps you solve it.

Comment: im already on this and hope to figure it out shortly