# Dockerfile and docker-desktop isn't working as intended composer install is installing dependencies but not available in container

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy laravel project to docker and defined following `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_web
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
            SERVICE_URL: http://clear_api:8080
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        volumes:
            - ./web/point1:/var/www/html
            - ./scripts/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    server:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_server
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
            - "4443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./web/point1:/var/www/html
            - ./scripts/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
COPY ./web/point1/ /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base shadow vim curl ...

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN composer install
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

RUN mv .env.example .env

RUN php artisan key:generate

RUN php artisan route:clear
RUN php artisan config:clear
RUN php artisan cache:clear
RUN php artisan storage:link

RUN php artisan key:generate

# RUN php artisan route:cache
RUN php artisan config:cache

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
    /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

While building the containers, `composer install` does install the dependencies but in the container it self the dependencies (vendor folder) are not available.

How would I fix this along with permissions for storage folder?

Didn't get fix from the answer mentioned here

[composer install in Dockerfile not saving dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350879/composer-install-in-dockerfile-not-saving-dependencies)

UPDATE: dependencies are being installed as seen in following image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nefIi.png

Image of container using `ls -lah`. `vendor` or `.env` doesn't exist

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEKf3.png

Comment: Could you add an image of what is shown when you run `ls -lah` inside the container? You said you don't have the `vendor` folder at all? I would also not run the install and all of that inside the image... that is initialization but not image creation

Comment: @matiaslauriti, Question updated with `ls -lah` log

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to contain the actual Dockerfile and the requested diagnostics as plain text (not images) directly in the question (not behind a GitHub link)?

Comment: (From the description, without seeing any of the code: are you running Composer in your Dockerfile, then maybe using a volume mount to inject host code, but that volume mount hides the packages Composer installed?)

Comment: @DavidMaze It seems so yes. The volume seems to override the container files. Any solution to this case?

Comment: Do not copy the code in your Dockerfile AND use a volume (see docker-compose.yml) at the same time. It's either, or. After deploying Docker, will you be editing your code and then checking the site? Then just don't copy the code within your Dockerfile, use volumes instead. Same goes for your .env file, that's what the volume is for